# Function to find Negative binomial distribution in Julia

Tags: r, julia

I am using below code to find Negative binomial distribution in R

```
dnbinom(n11, size=p[1], prob=p[2]/(p[2]+E))
```

where `dnbinom` is the function used for finding **Negative binomial distribution**
n11 & E are vector of integer.

Now i want to run the same code in Julia, which function should i have to use inplace of `dnbinom`

The function must have arguments as (x,size,prob)

where **x** = vector of probabilities.

**size** = target for number of successful trials, or dispersion parameter (the shape parameter of the gamma mixing distribution). Must be strictly positive, need not be integer.

**prob** = probability of success in each trial. 0 < prob <= 1.

Below is My full Code(Updated as per answers given, but still not working)

```
using Distributions  
data = query("Select count_a,EXP_COUNT from SM_STAT_ALGO_LOCALTRADE_SOC;")  
f([0.2,0.06,1.4,1.8,0.1],data[:,1],data[:,2])  

function f(x::Vector,n11,E)  
    return sum(-log(x[5] * pdf(NegativeBinomial(x[1], x[2]/(x[2]+E), n11)) + (1-x[5]) * pdf(NegativeBinomial(x[3], x[4]/(x[4]+E),n11))))  
end
```

Comment: http://distributionsjl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/univariate.html#negativebinomial

Comment: It's not a listed reason for closure but I do think that requests for us to read the documentation for one also deserves closure.

Comment: @Khashaa thanks for replying. `NegativeBinomial(r, p)` is taking only 2 arguments, I have to pass 3 arguments as i mentioned in my question. Can you tell me how can i pass those 3 arguments?

Comment: The first parameter for the R call is the number of random draws. Presumably Julia, being an optimized compiled language, will be able to deliver those efficiently from a for-loop... or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want the probabilities of a vector of outcomes, you can do

```
using Distributions
function dnbinom(x, size, prob)
    dist = NegativeBinomial(size,prob)
    map(y->pdf(dist,y), x)
end
@show dnbinom([3,5], 10, 0.1)
```

Comment: Hey @lianDunning thanks for replying. i have edited/added my full code in my question. Still it is giving error. can you help me out?

Comment: Error : `WARNING: x::Union(NAtype,Number) / A::AbstractDataArray is deprecated, use x ./ A instead.
 in f at hello.jl:16
LoadError("hello.jl",27,MethodError(NegativeBinomial,(1.2,[0.0218978,0.00773196,0.125,0.3,0.117647,0.428571,0.230769,0.0204082,0.105263,0.0130435  …  0.0126582,0.333333,0.545455,0.0037037,0.0638298,0.00724638,0.0833333,0.0167598,0.0769231,0.00483481])))`

Comment: What version of Julia are you using?

Comment: **Julia 0.3.4 - win64**

Answer (score 2):

To get the equivilaent of `dbinom` in R

```
dnbinom(1, 1, 0.5)
# [1] 0.25
```

you can use

```
using Distributions
pdf(NegativeBinomial(), 1)
# 0.25000000000000006
```

in julia.